# Justifying The Rule for Multiplication of Equivalence Classes of Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am supposed to prove that $+$ (addition) and $\cdot$ (multiplication) are binary operations on $\cfrac {F[x]}{p(x)}$.

My book uses this definition:

Let $F$ be a field and $p(x)$ a polynomial with coefficients in $F $irreducible in and $F[x]$.

We let $\cfrac{F[x]}{p(x)}$ stand for the polynomials with coefficients in $F\mod {p(x)}$,

with members of the equivalence classes $r(x)+p(x)q(x), \text{where} \space q(x)\space \text{is an element of} \space F[x]$,

represented by $r(x)\mod {p(x)}$.

Binary operation means combining two elements of a set gives an element of the set.

I think I can justify addition like this:

Let $r(x) + p(x)q(x)$ and $s(x) + p(x)u(x)$ be two equivalence classes in $\cfrac{F[x]}{p(x)}$.

Then $r(x) + p(x)q(x)$ + $s(x) + p(x)u(x) = (r(x)+s(x)) + p(x)[q(x)+u(x)]$

If $r(x)+s(x)$ is a remainder and $[q(x)+u(x)]$ is an element of $F[x]$, then

$(r(x)+s(x)) + p(x)[q(x)+u(x)]$ is an element of $\cfrac{F[x]}{p(x)}$ and $+$ is a binary operation.

The fact that $r(x)$ and $s(x)$ were remainders in their equivalence classes tells us that

$\text{degree}[r(x)] < \text{degree}[p(x)]$ and $\text{degree}[s(x)] < \text{degree}[p(x)]$.

Therefore $\text{degree}[r(x)+s(x)] < \text{degree}[p(x)]$ and $r(x)+s(x)$ is a valid remainder.

The fact that $q(x)$ and $u(x)$ are elements of $F[x]$ tells us that $q(x)+u(x)$ is an element of $F[x]$.

So $(r(x)+s(x)) + p(x)[q(x)+u(x)]$ is an element of $\cfrac {F[x]}{p(x)}$ and $+$ is a binary operation, which

could be written $r(x)\mod {p(x)} + s(x)\mod {p(x)} = [r(x)+s(x)]\mod {p(x)}$.

I run into a problem when I try to justify multiplication:

$$r(x) + p(x)q(x) \cdot s(x) + p(x)u(x) \\
= (r(x) \cdot s(x)) +\left[p(x)u(x)r(x)+p(x)q(x)s(x)+p(x)q(x)p(x)u(x)\right]
\\ =(r(x) \cdot s(x)) + p(x)\left[u(x)r(x)+q(x)s(x)+q(x)p(x)u(x)\right]$$

This looks to be the right form to be an element of $\cfrac{F[x]}{p(x)}$, with a possible remainder term and

a term containing $p(x)$ times something.

However, to be a valid remainder term, we require $\text{degree}[r(x)\cdot s(x)] < \text{degree}[p(x)]$.

The fact that $\text{degree}[r(x)] < \text{degree}[p(x)]$ and $\text{degree}[s(x)] < \text{degree}[p(x)]$ does not guarantee that

$\text{degree}[r(x)\cdot s(x)] < \text{degree}[p(x)]$, so I am stuck here.

Comment: Please format this

Comment: I submitted an edit.

Comment: Your expansion of the polynomial multiplication would benefit from more parentheses (I'll turn my hand to it if you like).  But you are correct that the degree of the product of two reduced residues need not be less than the degree of $p(x)$.  This isn't really a problem in showing  what you wanted.

Comment: I agree that I dropped a few '(x)' characters but don't agree with the other changes some people have made. I am totally bewildered as to what I should do next to get the content of my question addressed.

Comment: Before trying to deal with polynomials, first prove that ℤ/16ℤ is a ring, and ask yourself what the product of  7/16ℤ and 3/16ℤ are, noting that 7×3 > 16.